# Mongoose: Is it possible to make a query on all jsons that contain a substring?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose and my schema is:

```
   const DeliverySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    startPlace:{type: String,required: true},
    endPlace:{type: String,required: true},
    
});
```

Assuming that the start and end fields contain places in google format: street and city. Is it possible to make a query given only the city and which returns all the JSON that have that city in start or end as substring?

So if my record is:

```
startPlace:"Milano, MI, Italia",
endPlace:"Roma,RM,Italia"
```

And my query has parameter:

```
startPlace:"Milano"
```

It return me the JSON.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please show the query if u have tried any OR stuck somewhere. Might want to look up on [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({
 $or: [
  {
   startPlace: new RegExp('Milano', 'i')
  },
  {
   endPlace: new RegExp('Milano', 'i')
  }
 ]
}, {});`

Answer (score 1):

```
DeliverySchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          startPlace: {
            $regex: "Milano, ?.+, ?.+"
          }
        },
        {
          endPlace: {
            $regex: "Milano, ?.+, ?.+"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [{
                startPlace: {
                    $regex: ".*Milano.*"
                }
            },
            {
                endPlace: {
                    $regex: ".*Milano.*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ok-yoBia28U)